# How to Display Horizontal Button

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi Can I use Multiple stackLayout in Forms?

Below Layout Can not be displayed in the Android Phone:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mIWIS"
             x:Class="myApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical" Padding="20,20,20,20">
            <Label Text="Username" />
            <Entry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="username" />
            <Label Text="Password" />
            <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Password"  />           
            <Label x:Name="messageLabel" />         

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Button x:Name="BtnClear" Text="Clear" />
            <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Text="Login" />

        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>


</ContentPage>
```

Thanks

Comment: Wrap those 2 stack layouts in another stack layout

Comment: Dont get you. Can do a quick show how this is done? Only one stackLayout is allowed?

Comment: Content can be single element, so when you provide in content 2 stack layouts it doesn't work. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout>
        <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical" Padding="20,20,20,20">
            <Label Text="Username" />
            <Entry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="username" />
            <Label Text="Password" />
            <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Password"  />           
            <Label x:Name="messageLabel" />         

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Button x:Name="BtnClear" Text="Clear" />
            <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Text="Login" />

        </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```